# Raspberry Pi 4 won't reboot after unplugging power source

Tags: boot, boot-issues

I just got a Raspberry Pi 4 yesterday for the purpose of running a python script, it came with a brand new SD card, and the proper power cord. I had it all up and running through the NOOBS OS download, and I had my script running successfully. After running for a while, a family member needed to use the outlet it was plugged into and mistakenly unplugged it from the power source without shutting it down properly. When I plugged it back in, it had troubles booting. I tried formatting the SD card and re-downloading the NOOBS OS, it still doesn't work. Sometimes it will boot initially, and the won't boot after the OS install. Sometimes it will boot initially, boot again after the OS install, and fail to boot after the software update it asks for.

Also, when I put the SD card back into my Windows computer to format it, the name of it is "RECOVERY" and the partitions appear in multiple drives. I'm not sure if this is contributing to the issue.

Could the power cut have damaged any hardware of the Pi / SD card? Any ideas for a fix?

Comment: NOOBS causes more problems than it solves.  [Download Raspbian](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) and use the free [balenaEtcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) tool to flash it onto your SD card.  You shouldn't need to reformat the card, but if you do, use the [official SD card formatter](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter/) software.  (The Raspberry Pi Foundation has a [new imaging tool](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/) that also handles downloads.  I continue to recommend balenaEtcher because I'm sure it is reliable.)

Comment: try a different SD card - if you've **reflashed** NOOBS  and have the same issue, then it's either the pi or the sd card that is faulty

Comment: @JaromandaX the SD card was the problem, thank  you. I did a command line reformat and got the OS running again, while the SD formatter didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [SDCard Formatter](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter/) direct from the SD association to properly format the card before writing your image to it.  This should eliminate any issues with an SDCard.